# How to apply the default OS system's "medium" font in CSS

Tags: android, ios, css, fonts

I'm trying to have the default system "medium" (or "semibold" if you prefer) font displayed on various OS using CSS, eg:

- on Window: Segoe UI SemiBold
- on Android: Roboto Medium
- on iOS: ... is there one?

I've tried using:

```
font-family: Segoe UI, -apple-system, sans-serif;
font-weight: 600;
```

but I'm getting a fatter font than Roboto Medium on Android.

If I use this instead:

```
font-family: Segoe UI, -apple-system, sans-serif-medium, sans-serif;
font-weight: 600;
```

I'm getting a bolder than normal Roboto Medium font on Android.

What would be the best cross OS solution? Please note that if a "medium" font isn't available, I want to fall back to a bolder than normal font (thus the font-weight: 600). The solution needs to work on Windows, iOS and Android at least, and fallback graciously elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you want to achieve this you need to check which OS is making a call to your website. Therefore checking thye User Agent is one way to achieve the specific OS.

I would recommend you use this JS code:

```
var doc = document.documentElement;
doc.setAttribute('data-useragent', navigator.userAgent);
```

Then in your CSS you would have something like this:

```
html[data-useragent*='Mac OS X'] {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
}

html[data-useragent*='Android'] {
  font-family: "Roboto Medium", sans-serif; 
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

I would say that the  default font of iOS would be: Lucida Grande. But I am not sure so perhaps you can search for that

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a free Roboto font with medium weight from Google Fonts? It's support is excellent and you can set it's weight globally to 600, making it look consistently on a huge scale of devices.

Be aware though, for devices that do not support svg/woff/ttf fonts (thankfully not a lot of them currently in use), you will not be able to use this kind of font and would have to choose a fallback font.